# How do I make a drop down selection do something

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I'm new to this but I'm trying to write some code that makes my drop down do something. But:

1. I don't know where to put the code in the body of my program
2. I don't know how to call up the click and make it do something.

This code works in a bigger program but lets just say when the user clicks 'Independent' in the drop down. I would like the program to draw a box and then request input to lets say, add two numbers and then give the result with a close button.

```
 <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction2()">t-tests
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown2">
      <a href="#">One Sample</a>
      <a href="#">Independent (Group)</a>
      <a href="#">Dependent (Paired)</a>
      <a href="#">Calculate 'p' from known 't'</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]". It's important to show your attempt to solve the problem or, as you saw, we'll think you didn't try. Show the minimal example of what you wrote, describe the problem and then we can provide more usable help.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include which JavaScript frameworks if any you are already using on the page that has the dropdown; that will prevent an answer using a framework you don't already have installed. When a user interacts with an element on a page there will be events triggered. Good ones to start trying with in this case include "change" and "blur", which may be prefixed with "on" depending on how you are working with them.